# Permissions - Wordpress is unable to write in the parent directory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

When I try to upload a file into my WordPress which is hosted in Ubuntu 16.04 server in AWS cloud I get the following error:

```
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2017/07. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
```

I tried to change the permissions of the parent directory by using

```
chmod -R www-data:www-data *
```

But operations were not permitted.
`www-data` is My sudo user

Comment: Did you check uploads folder? if yes then try to save changes, just go to settings>media and then save changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aws should be using ec2, please follow the instruction in AWS to set the permission setting

```
sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user

exit

groups

sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www

sudo chmod 2775 /var/www

find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;

find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

ref. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Comment: I guess you are talking about Amazon Linux

Comment: It's the same, you can replace the group name to www-data if the group of /var/www/html is www-data

Answer (score 0):

You can change the ownership of your files using the command:

```
chown -Rf www-data:www-data /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Which is the path to your web root, change if different.
In my case it was `/var/www/html`

[Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/permission-problems-running-wordpress-on-nginx)